# How would I programmatically tell Visual Studio to load external modifications?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm writing a Visual Studio 2019 extension that performs the following:

```
CheckoutGitBranch("some-branch");
WaitUntilChangesAreLoadedIntoWorkspace(); // <-- How to implement?
AnalyzeCodeInWorkspace();
```

How do I wait until Visual Studio has loaded the changes into the workspace?

I've been considering listening for `VisualStudioWorkspace.WorkspaceChanged` events, but it's unclear when all of the changes have been integrated into the workspace.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT: I've been told in the Roslyn gitter chat that it's pretty much impossible, and that the best bet is to use a delay.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of VS (16.5 as of this writing) there is a new API you can MEF import called [IVsOperationProgressStatusService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.operationprogress.ivsoperationprogressstatusservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) which you can then ask the status of current operations. While it is not obvious the [Intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.operationprogress.commonoperationprogressstageids.intellisense?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) stage signifies a complete workspace update (The project system has processed all file updates and has sent them to the workspace).

```cs
CheckoutGitBranch("some-branch");
// Don't know how your extension is acquiring VS services, you can do this however you want.
// Including using MEF, grabbing it during package initialization etc. 
// Whichever method grabs this service does need to be on the UI thread though.
var operationProgress= await _serviceProvider.GetServiceAsync<SVsOperationProgress, IVsOperationProgressStatusService>(throwOnFailure: true);
IVsOperationProgressStageStatus intellisenseStatus = operationProgress.GetStageStatus(CommonOperationProgressStageIds.Intellisense);
await intellisenseStatus.WaitForCompletionAsync();
AnalyzeCodeInWorkspace();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jonathon. I'm going to try it out.

Note: IVsOperationProgressStatusService is available starting with Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework 16.1.28917.181

Comment: The docs say that `IVsOperationProgressStageStatus.WaitForCompletionAsync` _"Waits for the current work in progress to complete."_

I need to find a way to know that Visual Studio has in fact noticed the changes on disk and started working on it before I wait. I also need to know if the intellisense status stays busy the entire time, without moments of "completion" in-between changed projects etc.

Comment: Unfortunately `await intellisenseStatus.WaitForCompletionAsync();` completes before the workspace has changed.

Comment: You can query to see if a stage has been queued. If you've done a checkout and it says that no "intellisense" stage has been queued you know the work hasn't been processed yet.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathon. I've tested it in Visual Studio 2019 (16.4.1) and unfortunately the intellisense status only ever changes when I load a new solution, and not when files are modified externally. I've hooked up a callback to `IVsOperationProgressStageStatus.InProgressChanged` and I've tried awaiting `WaitForCompletionAsync` but it always returns the same number even though external changes are made.

Comment: Yep, as I said operation progress status was not enabled untilv16.5

Comment: Aah, gotcha, thanks for pointing that out again @Jonathon. I thought that since I did receive _some_ callbacks in 16.4.1 it meant that the functionality was running, just not adequate for my case. I'll update Visual Studio and give it another go.